# Minmax changes the current state and I could't figure out how to avoid this problem

Tags: python, minimax

I have implemented a modefied version of Dynamic Connect but I couldn't fix a problem I am facing which is apparantly the minimax alters the current state when it searches the tree. The minimax returns the right move but it doesn't apply it correctly.

```
def humanPolicy(game, state, player=-1):
  instructions= input('Input action:')
  action = game.instructions_to_actions(state, instructions, player)
  return actin

def minimax(game, st, depth, player):
  def recurse(st, depth):
    if game.isEnd(state, player) or depth == 0:
      return (game.utility(st, player), 0)
    choices = [(recurse(game.action_succ(st, action, player), depth - 1)[0], action) for action in game.actions(st, player)]
    if player ==1:
      return (max(choices))
    elif player == -1:
      return min(choices)
  value, action = recurse(st, depth)
  print('minimax says action={}, value = {}'.format(action, value))
  return action

# stt = {}
w_list =  [(5, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7, 5), (3, 7)]
b_list = [(4, 1), (3, 1), (7, 2), (1, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7)]

policies = {1: humanPolicy, -1: minimax}
game = DynamicConnect(w_list, b_list)
state = game.InitialState()
st = state
player = 1
depth = 3
while True:

  board = [['.' for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
  
  if player == 1:
    print('Player: White: O')
  else:
    print('Player: Black: X')
  print(state)
  for (x, y) in state[0]:
    board[y-1][x-1] = 'O'
  for (x, y) in state[1]:
    board[y-1][x-1] = 'X'
  print(*(' '.join(row) for row in board), sep='\n')
  print('='*10, state)
  # policy = policies[player]
  if player == 1:
    action = humanPolicy(game, state, player)
  else:
    action = minimax(game, st,depth, player)
  print(action)
  state = game.action_succ(st, action, player)
  st = state
  player = -player
  if game.isEnd(state, player):
    print('Game over')

print('utility = {}'.format(game.utility(state, player)))
print(state)
```

This is the action successor function which return a new state but when it receives the action from the minimax it doesn't work properly.

```
def action_succ(self, state, action, player): 

    initial_pos = action[0]
    new_pos = action[1]
    if player == -1:
      if initial_pos in state[1]:
        state[1][state[1].index(initial_pos)] = new_pos
    else:
      if initial_pos in state[0]:
        state[0][state[0].index(initial_pos)] = new_pos
    return (state)
```